Boost Asio: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand
I'm trying to use boost asio to send some udp packets, but I am getting:
[main] Building folder: C:/Users/tom.mclean/src/Nemo/build nemo
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Scripts\cmake.EXE --build C:/Users/tom.mclean/src/Nemo/build --parallel 18 --target nemo --
[build] [0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[build] [1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\nemo.dir\nemo\nemo.cpp.obj
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/nemo.dir/nemo/nemo.cpp.obj 
[build] C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DBOOST_CONTAINER_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_CONTAINER_NO_LIB -DBOOST_CONTEXT_DYN_LINK="" -DBOOST_CONTEXT_EXPORT=EXPORT -DBOOST_CONTEXT_NO_LIB="" -DBOOST_COROUTINES_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_COROUTINE_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_COROUTINE_NO_LIB -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_UUID_FORCE_AUTO_LINK -DEZXML_NOMMAP -DFMI4C_STATIC -DHAVE_MEMMOVE=1 -DUSE_FILE32API -IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\Nemo\external\ODSClient\include -IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\Nemo\external\fmi4c\include -IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\Nemo\external\fmi4c\3rdparty -IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\Nemo\external\fmi4c\3rdparty\minizip -external:IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\Nemo -external:IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\vcpkg_installed\x86-windows\include -external:IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\vcpkg_installed\x86-windows\include\eigen3 -external:IC:\Users\tom.mclean\src\vcpkg_installed\x86-windows\include\SDL2 -external:W0 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -std:c++20 -MD /bigobj /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\nemo.dir\nemo\nemo.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\nemo.dir\nemo.pdb /FS -c C:\Users\tom.mclean\src\Nemo\nemo\nemo.cpp
[build] Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
[build] - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
[build] - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
[build] Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
[build] C:\Users\tom.mclean\src\vcpkg_installed\x86-windows\include\boost/asio/co_composed.hpp(162): error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand
[build] C:\Users\tom.mclean\src\vcpkg_installed\x86-windows\include\boost/asio/co_composed.hpp(163): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::asio::detail::co_composed_state_return<Executors,Handler,boost::asio::detail::co_composed_returns<Signatures...>>' being compiled
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Scripts\cmake.EXE --build C:/Users/tom.mclean/src/Nemo/build --parallel 18 --target nemo -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:08.065
[build] Build finished with exit code 1

My minimal example is:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint server_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"), 12345);
        boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_context);
        socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
        const std::string message = "Hello, UDP Server!";
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), server_endpoint);
        std::cout << "Message sent to server: " << message << std::endl;

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

And my CMakeLists.txt is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
set(BOOST_ALL_STATIC_LIB ON)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

project(test VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
find_package(boost_asio CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Boost::asio)
target_compile_features(main PUBLIC cxx_std_20)

The error seems to come from target_compile_features(main PUBLIC cxx_std_20). If I set it to target_compile_features(main PUBLIC cxx_std_17) it compiles fine. I thought C++ was backwards compatible, so why does this break?
Github repo of error: https://github.com/mcleantom/so-79276056

Please show the actual compiler output rather than that json which is just a summary. We'll also need a [mre] that reproduces the error

@AlanBirtles Added the compiler output

we still need a [mre] too

Note that all you've really shown is the 'summarized' build log.  There's no indication (as far as I can see at least) as to the location of the problem in your own code.

A minimal example should just be a few lines of code that reproduces the bug (and that we can ideally also try out on godbolt.org or our local compilers). The actual compilation errors should be mentioned  (with a clear direction to the actual source code line)

@G.M. That was the full output of my compiler, I cant see any problems in my code so I dont know why the error is happening

@PepijnKramer I am making a minimal example now, I couldnt get godbolt to work with boost and the MSVC compiler so I am trying to make a github repo

How are you building -- cmake or 'raw' ninja?  If you're using cmake try using VERBOSE=1 cmake ... -- it should show the real/full compiler output.

@G.M. I was using vscode, but it's generated command was: C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Scripts\cmake.EXE --build C:/Users/tom.mclean/src/Nemo/build --parallel 18, when I run that with the --verbose flag nothing extra is shown

@TomMcLean Yes, my bad -- I should've spotted that.  Still, as stated by others, we need a [mcve] and an error message that points to the specific location in the example that's causing the error.

Godbolt with boost : https://godbolt.org/z/63rvPcobx (note the green box, libraries). Linking to github from a question is not a good idea.

Ive added a github repo, it seems to only happen when I do: target_compile_features(main PUBLIC cxx_std_20), setting it to cpp 17 works fine

@PepijnKramer I tried that but when I set it to the MSVC compiler, it said it could not include boost headers

Then use gcc or clang, shouldn't matter as musch long as you use standard C++ + boost

@PepijnKramer Tried putting my minimal example in godbolt with the gcc compiler and setting the -std=c++20 flag, but I wasnt getting the same compiler error

Ok that's a shame

What version of boost are you compiling against?

@G.M. 1.86.0 (https://vcpkg.io/en/package/boost-asio)

Kudos for the excellent self-contained example in the Github repo.
So, I dusted off my Windows installation, installed VS2022, CMake, vcpkg, Ninja and Github Desktop to reproduce this.

It turns out it doesn't reproduce for me. This is both before and after I applied the updates to 17.12.3
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.12.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.12.3+35527.113
Installed Version: Community
Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA007
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022


Thanks for trying for me, I am not sure why I am getting the error. Luckily for my project I could actually use c++ 17 but would be good to work out why c++ 20 didnt work
